# Main term in the number of sign changes of $\psi(x) - x$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, prime-number-theorem

Define $N_\Delta(T)$ to be the number of sign changes of $\psi(x) - x$ in the interval $[1, T]$.

Landau's Theorem says $N_\Delta(T)$ is $\Omega(\log T)$ [1].

But perhaps that estimate is too crude. Is the main term of $N_\Delta(T)$ known? Or are only strict upper and lower bounds known?

What type of machinery is used to determine something of this nature?

---

[1] Emil Grosswald "Oscillation Theorems of Arithmetical Functions" *Transactions of the American Mathematical Society* **126** (1967) pp. 7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An asymptotic for the number of sign changes is not known, and indeed only a lower bound of $c \log T$ is known.  There have been small improvements in the constant $c$ that is allowed here (see [Kaczorowski](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa44/aa4446.pdf)).   For recent work related to this, see [Montgomery and Vorhauer](https://www.projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.facm/1229442626), who show that the remainder term changes sign in any interval $[x,2.02x]$ once $x$ is large enough.  They also speculate that the right order for the number of sign changes up to $T$ is $\sqrt{T}$  (every once in a while $\psi(x)-x$ will be very small, and near that point there'll be many sign changes).  One more recent reference is a paper of [Kaczorowski and Wiertelak](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2009-361-09/S0002-9947-09-04803-X/S0002-9947-09-04803-X.pdf).

Also one shouldn't really expect an asymptotic formula for the number of sign changes -- if $\psi(x)-x$ is large and positive (on scale $\sqrt{x}$)  then it is likely to stay positive at $1.01x$ as well.  Montgomery and Vorhauer speculate that
$$ 
0< \liminf_{T\to \infty} \frac{N_{\Delta}(T)}{\sqrt{T}} < \limsup_{T\to\infty} \frac{N_{\Delta}(T)}{\sqrt{T}} < \infty. 
$$

Comment: Great, thanks! Do you have a source for knowing the main term is unknown, or is that something you "just know"?

Comment: Well the paper by Montgomery and Vorhauer clearly states this, and this hasn't changed in the last ten years.

Comment: Ah, I missed that part. Thanks again.

Comment: Without assuming the RH it seems obvious we can't estimate the number of sign changes of $\displaystyle \frac{\psi(e^u)-e^u}{e^{u/2}}=\mathcal{O}(e^{-u/2})+\sum_\rho \frac{e^{(\rho-1/2) u}}{\rho}$. But assuming the RH, the number of sign changes of $\displaystyle Re(\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{e^{i \frac{2 \pi n}{\ln n} u}}{1/2+i \frac{2 \pi n}{\ln n}})$ should provide a good estimate ?